# How much data consumed on MQTT connection

Tags: mqtt

I wonder how much data will be consumed (approximately) over say one month if I just connected to an MQTT server.(without sending or receiving any messages).

I need to calculate it to measure what data plan should I recharge for my sim card used in IoT application.

Thanks

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing how many message you will send and what the size of the payload is.

Comment: I need to know how much data will be consumed without sending any messages, just the connection link !!

Comment: This is still unanswerable, we would need to know what keep alive you set and how stable the link is (how many times the client has to reconnect). But the protocol is designed to use the bare minimum of data above and beyond the payload.

Comment: Thanks, seems like there's a lot of things that I know nothing about. You last comment really helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: fix broken link as suggested by @Jacob

I hope that you can find your answers here:

[MQTT data usage](https://docs.devicewise.com/Content/Products/IoT_Portal_API_Reference_Guide/MQTT_Interface/MQTT-data-usage.htm)

By the way... The client sets the keep alive value when it sends a CONNECT request to the server (aka *the broker*).
Potentially, if the client choose 0 as keep alive value, no data is consumed except for setup connection.

Comment: link above is broken, reposting what I think is the new link:
https://docs.devicewise.com/Content/Products/IoT_Portal_API_Reference_Guide/MQTT_Interface/MQTT-data-usage.htm

Ranges from 298kb to 1.4mb per month

Answer (score 2):

Last time I had to do something similar I simulated the traffic of a month.

Because computers are much faster than IoT devices, just use any kind of high-level library to send the traffic the IoT devices would be sent in a month and then measure the TCP traffic.

Comment: Thanks, that's right but I am waiting for someone who already did the experiment!

Comment: But that depends on what you expect to send to the MQTT server (I guess IoT devices provides information and they are not subscribed to your servers).

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know if I didn't send anything, just open an MQTT channel, and then I will add my data sent to and from the device to it.

Comment: If you don't send any data, the amount of data will be very small, less than a kilobyte I would say.

Comment: As far as I know, MQTT does not have a keepalive process or something similar. MQTT does not send anything passively.

Comment: MQTT does send keep alive packets, the keep alive timeout can be set at connection time.